# Did Gnosis signMessage function change?

Tags: ethers.js, gnosis-safe, gnosis

I have sort of a beginner question,
I'm deploying a gnosis safe with three owners and a threshold of 2, and i wanted to sign a message from one of the owners and read somewhere that i should write the code like this:

```
      const sig1 = safe.connect(daoMember1).signMessage(makerMessageHashBinary)
      const sig2 = safe.connect(daoMember2).signMessage(makerMessageHashBinary)
```

but gnosis safe contract doesn't have a signMessage function, it has a approveHash function
so is this function(approveHahs) the equivalent of sign message in gnosis?
and i should change my code to this?

```
      const sig1 = safe.connect(daoMember1).approveHash(makerMessageHashBinary)
      const sig2 = safe.connect(daoMember2).approveHash(makerMessageHashBinary)
```

and if you can send me a link to a repo that'd doing the same thing I would appreciate it.